# How to change ruby version on linux

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemfile

I installed rvm on my Linux machine and download simple project from github. I tried to run rails s, but got a error with ruby version:

I executed next commands:

- rvm install ruby-2.3.0
- rvm use ruby-2.3.0
- rvm use ruby-2.3.0 --default

When I opened the project and ran rails s, I got this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsuKH.png

## Update

My Gemfile has ruby 2.3.0

Can't run bundle install because of this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSIgh.jpg
w

which rails, which ruby: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1DUr.jpg

Comment: If you go into the directory and execute the command rvm current, what do you get?

Comment: I got ruby-2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used rvm, but I'm using rbenv for version management.

From what I've read, it works similarly, although the commands are a little bit different.

Did command `rvm use ruby-2.3.0` inside the project folder generate a file called `.ruby_version`?

It should list the current version of ruby used in this project

Comment: how about `which rails` and `which ruby`?

Comment: looks like your `rails` is not linked to rvm and that's why you're facing this issue.
Run `bundle install` inside project and try `which rails` again.

Comment: Could you check `which gem` and `which bundle` after doing `gem install bundler`?

Comment: Have you installed ruby with sudo?

Comment: try `bundle install` now inside the project

Comment: @Shimu I installed ruby via rvm, without sudo

Comment: I'm not sure about security of this (it should be fine since it's not on a public server) but try `chmod -R 777 ~/.bundle` (sudo if it fails) and then try `bundle install` again inside the project

Comment: @Egor  Then I would suggest you delete `.bundle` dir. And then `rvm reinstall all`.

Answer (score 0):

After checked the errors on your updated screenshot, I think it's better just do this:

```
rm -r ~/.bundle
bundle
bundle install
```

Maybe just

```
rvm reinstall all
```

then try again.

If permission error happens, run

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

And then do it again.

Comment: I don't need to use 2.3.1, I need to use 2.3.0 that is why I deleted 2.3.1

Comment: My Gemfile has ruby 2.3.0, that what I need for my purposes, I should not change Gemfile